# Need attribute of clicked link, using LocalScroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I am using the ScrollTo and LocalScroll plugins.
Basically I just want to determine if the clicked link has a particular class added to it.  I know how to do this normally, but here I want to do it in the onBefore function when calling the plugin, if possible.  I've tried accessing it using the anchor keyword but sofar I'm not getting anywhere.

Here is the function:

```
$.localScroll({
      duration:800,
      onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){

      }
});
```

Comment: Was that really a question lol .... $ is used for inheriting the plugins methods

Comment: @josh He was only asking for clarification so that he could try to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).hasClass('className')) {
    //Code
}
```

Should help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.localScroll({
  duration:800,
  onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
    if ($(ancor).hasClass('your_class')) {
    }
  }
});
```